# Observing PEP maximum line size, particularly when formatting localized timestamps

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.x

I have this function that I use to publish a message but I need to do this long conversion for time and date. Maybe there's a better way to convert it to make smaller. Otherwise I'm stuck with this long line. I guess I could use slashes, is guidelines on readability for using slashing or is arbitrary.

```
  SMS.publish('/jobs',{
                           'batchdate': job.get('batchdate'),
                           'job': job.get('name'),
                            'Script execution date (EST)':pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.time())).astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                             'Start time(EST)':pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(job.get('starttime')))).astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                            'Current runtime': change_format_num( cur_runtime),
                            'Average runtime': change_format_num(avg_time)
                                     })
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, notice the duplicated parts in these long expressions:

```
pytz.utc.localize(
    datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.time())).astimezone(
    pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

pytz.utc.localize(
    datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(job.get('starttime')))).astimezone(
    pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Having duplicated code segments is both inconvenient and error-prone.
If you want to / need to change anything later,
you have to remember to do that in all places,
and it's easy to make a mistake.

So it will be good to extract this to a helper function:

```
def get_formatted_time(val):
    return pytz.utc.localize(
        datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(val)).astimezone(
        pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

You can break lines within parentheses.
Now this looks fairly tidy, and it's PEP8 compliant.

Using this helper you can rewrite the original code becomes simpler:

```
SMS.publish('/jobs', {
    'batchdate': job.get('batchdate'),
    'job': job.get('name'),
    'Script execution date (EST)': get_formatted_time(time.time()),
    'Start time(EST)': get_formatted_time(float(job.get('starttime'))),
    'Current runtime': change_format_num(cur_runtime),
    'Average runtime': change_format_num(avg_time)
})
```